# How to create Telegram's on boarding animation with React Native?

Tags: android, ios, animation, reactjs, native

The effect is visible when the user swipes and there is a smooth animation on the picture: http://youtu.be/HNS5Lo9ZIcQ

Comment: This seems like more of an animation question than a programming question. It's hard to know how the animation was added to the UI... it could be a video element, or a SVG image, or even an animated GIF. As for how the animation itself was done, well it could have been anything from hand-written CSS or created with a tool like Flash (Animate) Pro and exported to a compatible format.